# Module in python working in one python IDE and not another (WINDOWS)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I have 2 python IDE, namely IDLE and Anaconda. I installed a module called `pykalman` as follows:

```
easy_install pykalman
```

When i ran the command

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
```

in Anaconda terminal, it worked. But the same thing in IDLE gave the usual import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from pykalman import KalmanFilter
ImportError: No module named pykalman
```

So i checked the python instalaltion path for each IDE by using the command:

```
sys.executable
```

For IDLE, i got:

```
(local directory)\Documents\\Python\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe
```

For Anaconda, i got:

```
(local directory)\Anaconda\\pythonw.exe
```

So i suspected that `easy_install` has somehow been configured to work only with the Anaconda Python, and ignores IDLE. Why? How to rectify this? Why is `easy_install` behaving this way?
Also my IDLE python is:

```
2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014, 17:36:35) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

whereas Anaconda python is:

```
2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

My second question is how will 2 different python versions give rise to future conflicts when i try to install new modules. How to take care of such problems in future? I want to retain both the IDEs but want to have only 1 python version to avoid conflicts in future.

Comment: with pip (as an example of package installs for python) you can force the target version of python to receive the install via eg: `/some/version/python -m pip install pykalman`. In general if multiple python versions are really needed in parallel, virtual environments are helpful (esp. avoiding to do funny things to the system python version). Best leave the OS provided default python version "alone" and focus on a controlled python version for your development. Every platform has offerings for this and python offers virtualenv and then there is docker ,...

Comment: @Dilettant The business of not disturbing OS default python and working on a controlled python version is quite appealing. Could you please point to a source that elaborates on this approach in a more detailed manner and from scratch? And how to find which is the "OS provided default python version"?

Comment: Windows does not provide Python by default, so there is no "OS provided default python version" here. I would strongly suggest you look into using either OS X or Linux in a virtual machine or dual boot; getting Python to work in Windows has historically been quite painful, and the effort needed to get a Linux instance working with your Python setup could very well be less than the effort needed to get Python working in Windows.